# Pandas lookup values from different columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for the best way of solving the following problem in Pandas.  Given a dataframe `df`, e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
dt = pd.date_range('1/1/2014', periods=10, freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0.,0.,0.,1.,0.,0.,1.,0.,0.,0.],'B':[0.,0.,0.,0.,1.,0.,0.,0.,0.,1.]},index=dt)

df
                     A  B
2014-01-01 00:00:00  0  0
2014-01-01 01:00:00  0  0
2014-01-01 02:00:00  0  0
2014-01-01 03:00:00  1  0
2014-01-01 04:00:00  0  1
2014-01-01 05:00:00  0  0
2014-01-01 06:00:00  1  0
2014-01-01 07:00:00  0  0
2014-01-01 08:00:00  0  0
2014-01-01 09:00:00  0  1
```

then for each row where `B=1` I would like to find the index of the last row before that where `A=1`, i.e.

```
                     A  B                    C
2014-01-01 04:00:00  0  1  2014-01-01 03:00:00
2014-01-01 09:00:00  0  1  2014-01-01 06:00:00
```

Not sure what the easiest way is to do this on Pandas while also being reasonably efficient for large dataframes.

Update:
Should have made clear in my original question that I'd like this to work where there is potentially more than one `A=1` per `B=1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one idea - there may be something better.

Populate a a column `C` with index values where `A` is 1.

```
df['C'] = np.where(df['A'] == 1, df.index, '')
```

Forward fill the missing values, so it represents that last time `A` was one.

```
df['C'] = df['C'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

Finally, fill all the values where `B` is not 1 with missing values.

```
df['C'] = np.where(df['B'] == 1, df['C'], '')


In [108]: df
Out[108]: 
                     A  B                   C
2014-01-01 00:00:00  0  0                 NaT
2014-01-01 01:00:00  0  0                 NaT
2014-01-01 02:00:00  0  0                 NaT
2014-01-01 03:00:00  1  0                 NaT
2014-01-01 04:00:00  0  1 2014-01-01 03:00:00
2014-01-01 05:00:00  0  0                 NaT
2014-01-01 06:00:00  1  0                 NaT
2014-01-01 07:00:00  0  0                 NaT
2014-01-01 08:00:00  0  0                 NaT
2014-01-01 09:00:00  0  1 2014-01-01 06:00:00
```

Comment: Like this one for being clear and easy to understand.

Comment: The most recent updates to numpy appear to have broken this.  It works with the following changes to the `np.where` calls: `df['C'] = np.where(df['A'] == 1, df.index, pd.NaT)`; `df['C'] = df['C'].fillna(method='ffill')`; `df['C'] = np.where(df['B'] == 1, df['C'], pd.NaT)`

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the answer from @jeanrjc is not stable if you have more than one `A` value per `B` splitted group. To show this, I manipulate the given dataframe:

```
In[217]: df.iloc[2]['A'] = 1
In[218]: df
Out[218]: 
                     A  B
2014-01-01 00:00:00  0  0
2014-01-01 01:00:00  0  0
2014-01-01 02:00:00  1  0
2014-01-01 03:00:00  1  0
2014-01-01 04:00:00  0  1
2014-01-01 05:00:00  0  0
2014-01-01 06:00:00  1  0
2014-01-01 07:00:00  0  0
2014-01-01 08:00:00  0  0
2014-01-01 09:00:00  0  1
```

He proceeds to take the timestamp from where ever `df.A == 1` - if that happens more than once per subgroup, you have an error.

```
In[219]: new_df["C"] = df.index[np.where(df.A==1)[0]]
Traceback (...)
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Instead, I create an array that collects the correct indices. If you want to understand what happens, try to understand it from the outside (first, what is `df.loc[:b]` given my for loop, then the next sub selection etc).

```
In[239]: new_df['C'] = [df.loc[:b][df.loc[:b].A == 1].iloc[-1].name for b in df.loc[df.B == 1].index ]
In[240]: new_df
Out[240]: 
                     A  B                   C
2014-01-01 04:00:00  0  1 2014-01-01 03:00:00
2014-01-01 09:00:00  0  1 2014-01-01 06:00:00
```

Comment: Also good answer, as this could easily be extended to do more complicated things, e.g. for each row, find the index of the previous row where A>= current B, i.e. `new_df['C'] = [df.loc[:b][df.loc[:b].A >= df.loc[b,'B']].iloc[-1].name for b in df.index]`

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this:

```
new_df = df[df.B==1]
new_df["C"] = df.index[np.where(df.A==1)[0]]

new_df

                     A  B                   C
2014-01-01 04:00:00  0  1 2014-01-01 03:00:00
2014-01-01 09:00:00  0  1 2014-01-01 06:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do. Easy to understand and readable

```
import pandas as pd
dt = pd.date_range('1/1/2014', periods=10, freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0.,0.,0.,1.,0.,0.,1.,0.,0.,0.],
                   'B':[0.,0.,0.,0.,1.,0.,0.,0.,0.,1.]},
                   index=dt)

# How I would do it
temp = np.where(df['B']==1)[0]
newdf = df.iloc[temp]
temp2 = np.where(df['A']==1)[0]
newdf['C'] = df.iloc[temp2].index
```

which prints

```
In [8]: newdf
Out[8]: 
                     A  B                   C
2014-01-01 04:00:00  0  1 2014-01-01 03:00:00
2014-01-01 09:00:00  0  1 2014-01-01 08:00:00
```

Comment: This is not what the OP was asking. The OP asked for the last row before B=1 where A=1.